# Gershgorin Circle theorem- implications

Tags: matrices, gershgorin-sets

(I am considering only real matrices)

Does only hold that if the area of all Gershgorin Circles is positiv $\Rightarrow$ the Matrix is positiv definit (trivial)

or does also follow the vice versa

the Matrix is positiv definit $\Rightarrow$ the area of all Gershgorin Circles is positiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse direction does not hold:
$$
A=\pmatrix{ 1 & 2\\ 2 & 10}
$$
is positive definite, but the Gershgorin circle for the first row contains numbers with negative real part.

Comment: Thanks, I found something like it for special matrices in my old exercise papers and was wondering if I can use it to check if a $LL^T$ Cholesky decomposition is possible, seems it is not the case, thanks